# Finding Max of column by subset of data

Tags: python, sql, r, sas, max

I have the below data set and would like to find the max by subset
**Data Set**

```
StudentID Indicator Value  
100 N 30  
100 N 35  
100 N 28  
100 Y 20  
100 N 29  
100 N 60  
200 N 40  
200 N 35  
200 Y 20  
200 N 24  
200 N 35
```

I would like the result to be as below:
**Result**

```
StudentID Indicator Value Max  
100 N 30 35  
100 N 35 35  
100 N 28 35  
100 N 29 60   
100 N 60 60  
200 N 40 40  
200 N 35 40  
200 N 24 35  
200 N 35 35
```

So essentially, whenever the Indicator changes from N to Y, I need to consider the rows by studentID and IndicatorID as one block and compute the max of that block and move on to the next iteration.

Comment: Which language are you actually using here?

Comment: Language doesnt really matter here. I'm fine with either Sql or R or Python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution using [dplyr](/questions/tagged/dplyr) in R.

```
library(dplyr)

dat2 <- dat %>%
  group_by(StudentID) %>%
  mutate(Group = cumsum(Indicator %in% "Y")) %>%
  filter(!Indicator %in% "Y") %>%
  group_by(StudentID, Group) %>%
  mutate(Max = max(Value)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  select(-Group) %>%
  as.data.frame(stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
dat2
#   StudentID Indicator Value Max
# 1       100         N    30  35
# 2       100         N    35  35
# 3       100         N    28  35
# 4       100         N    29  60
# 5       100         N    60  60
# 6       200         N    40  40
# 7       200         N    35  40
# 8       200         N    24  35
# 9       200         N    35  35
```

**DATA**

```
dat <- read.table(text = "StudentID Indicator Value  
100 N 30  
                  100 N 35  
                  100 N 28  
                  100 Y 20  
                  100 N 29  
                  100 N 60  
                  200 N 40  
                  200 N 35  
                  200 Y 20  
                  200 N 24  
                  200 N 35  ",
                  header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Comment: QQ : What if I had to consider the Indicator Y as well but when you switch from N to Y, the value corresponding to Y is considered in the first block.

Comment: @Vinay Add `mutate(Group = ifelse(Indicator %in% "Y", Group - 1, Group))` after the first `mutate` call.

Comment: Coding level = God level!

Answer (score 1):

Here is an option using `pandas` from `python`.  We create a grouping variable by getting the cumulative sum of the logical output (`dat.Indicator == "Y"`, then subset the rows by removing the rows that 'Indicator' as "Y", grouped by 'StudentID', 'Group', get the `max` of 'Value' with `transform`, assign it to 'Value', and `drop` the columns that are not in need

```
dat['Group'] = (dat.Indicator == "Y").cumsum()

datS = dat[dat.Indicator != "Y"]
datS1 = datS.copy()
datS1['Value'] = datS.groupby(['StudentID', 'Group'])['Value'].transform('max')
datS1.drop('Group', axis = 1, inplace = True)
datS1
```

-output

[image]

---

A `base R` option would be `ave`

```
dat$Value <- with(dat, ave(Value, cumsum(Indicator == "Y"), FUN = max))
subset(dat, Indicator != "Y")
#    StudentID Indicator Value
#1        100         N    35
#2        100         N    35
#3        100         N    35
#5        100         N    60
#6        100         N    60
#7        200         N    60
#8        200         N    60
#10       200         N    35
#11       200         N    35
```

#### data

```
import pandas as pd
dat = pd.DataFrame({'StudentID': [100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 200, 200, 200, 200, 200],
               'Indicator':[ "N", "N", "N", "Y", "N", "N", "N", "N", "Y", "N", "N"],
               'Value':[30, 35, 28, 20, 29, 60, 40, 35, 20, 24, 35]})

#R
dat <-structure(list(StudentID = c(100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 
 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L), Indicator = c("N", "N", "N", "Y", 
"N", "N", "N", "N", "Y", "N", "N"), Value = c(35L, 35L, 35L, 
60L, 60L, 60L, 60L, 60L, 35L, 35L, 35L)), .Names = c("StudentID", 
 "Indicator", "Value"), row.names = c(NA, -11L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a variable to indicate the groups.  You can do that easily in SAS using the `notsorted` option on the `by` statement.

```
data grouped ;
  retain group 0;
  set have ;
  by studentid indicator notsorted;
  group + first.indicator;
run;
```

There are a number of ways to now generate the mean value by group now that they are defined.  `PROC SQL` makes it easy by automatically remerging aggregate values back onto detail lines.

```
proc sql ;
 select *,max(value) as max
   from grouped
   group by group
 ;
quit;
```

Results:

```
group  StudentID  Indicator     Value       max

   1        100  N                35        35
   1        100  N                30        35
   1        100  N                28        35
   2        100  Y                20        20
   3        100  N                60        60
   3        100  N                29        60
   4        200  N                40        40
   4        200  N                35        40
   5        200  Y                20        20
   6        200  N                35        35
   6        200  N                24        35
```

I am not sure why your sample output has removed the groups that have INDICATOR='Y' but you could just add a `where` clause to remove them.

Answer (score -1):

A solution using `ddply` from the `plyr` package.

Assuming this is stored as a data frame called `df`

```
output_df <- plyr::ddply(df, c("StudentID", "Indicator"), numcolwise(max))
```

`ddply` applies a function to a subset of data. The first argument is the data we want to apply it to, the second is the column names we want to group it by. The final is the function we want to apply. Since we're applying it to a column of the subset we need to wrap `max` in `numcolwise`.

The output might have a funny name for the last column, but you can set that with `names(output_df)[3] <- "Max"`.

Now we just need to merge that with the original frame.

```
df$Max <- rep(output_df$Max, times = table(df$StudentID))
```

The `times` argument of `rep` says how many times to repeat each element of the first argument. Using the `table` function works out how many times each student ID occurs. This will only work if the student IDs are in order. If that's not the case then a different approach will be needed.

Altogether, that makes 3 lines of code

```
output_df <- plyr::ddply(df, c("StudentID", "Indicator"), numcolwise(max))
names(output_df)[3] <- "Max"
df$Max <- rep(output_df$Max, times = table(df$StudentID))
```